# How to upload video to cloudinary using MERN and FormData?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, multipartform-data, mern, cloudinary

```
                    let formData = new FormData()
                    formData.append("file", myfile)
                    console.log("uploading",formData,apiss)
                    const headers={
                        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                    }
                    apiss.post(`/video`, formData,{
                        headers:headers,
                        onUploadProgress: data => {
                            //Set the progress value to show the progress bar
                            console.log(Math.round((100 * data.loaded) / data.total))
                          },
                    }).then(vid=>{
                        console.log(vid,"myvidss",vid.data.msg)
                        this.setState({videourl:vid.data.msg,cool:"uploaded"})
                    })
                    .catch(err=>{
                        console.log("err",err)
                    })
                    // setFileInputState('');
                    // setPreviewSource('');
                    console.log('Video uploaded successfully');
```

```
app.post('/upload/video',async(req,res)=>{
        try{
            console.log("yes video",req,req.body,req.file,req.files)
            // console.log(req.body.data)
            // var ks;
            // for (var key of formData.entries()) {
            //     ks=key[1]
            //     console.log(key[1] + ', ' + key[1])
            // }
            const uploadreesp=await cloudinary.uploader.upload_large(req.body, {
                width: 800, height: 500, crop: "scale",
                resource_type: "auto", 
                public_id: "videos",
                chunk_size: 6000000,
                timeout:120000,
                folder:'videos',
                upload_preset: 'photos',
            })
            console.log(uploadreesp)
            res.json({ msg: uploadreesp.secure_url });
            console.log("uploaded video")
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err,"yes")
        }
    })
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import { unmountComponentAtNode } from "react-dom";
import api from "../api";
import Axios from "axios";

class VideosInsert extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            names: "",
            imageurl: "",
            videourl: "www.google.com",
            image :"",
            video:"",
            cool:"",
            cools:''
        };
    }
    handleChangeInputName = async (event) => {
        const names = event.target.value;
        this.setState({ names });
    };
    
 

    handleFileInputChange = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        // previewFile(file);
        this.setState({image:file,cools:'uploading'},()=>{
            if (this.state.image==="") return;
            const reader = new FileReader();
            console.log(this.state.image)
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.state.image);
    
            const uploadImage = async (base64EncodedImage) => {
                try {

                    const apiss = Axios.create({
                        baseURL: 'http://localhost:3005/upload',
                    })
                    var body=JSON.stringify({ data: base64EncodedImage });
                    console.log("uploading",body,apiss)
                    const headers={
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                    apiss.post(`/image`, body,{
                        headers:headers
                    }).then(vid=>{
                        console.log(vid,"myvid",vid.data.msg)
                        this.setState({imageurl:vid.data.msg,cools:"uploaded"})
                    })
                    .catch(err=>{
                        console.log("err",err)
                    })
                    // setFileInputState('');
                    // setPreviewSource('');
                    console.log('Image uploaded successfully');
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    console.log('Something went wrong!');
                }
    
    
    
        };
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            uploadImage(reader.result);
        };
    
    
    
    
        reader.onerror = () => {
            console.error('AHHHHHHHH!!');
            console.log('something went wrong!');
        };
        });
    };

    handleFileVideoChange=async(e)=>{
        const myfile=e.target.files[0];
        console.log(e,e.target.value,myfile,myfile.path,e.target.files,myfile.name,myfile.result,"cool",myfile.path)
        this.setState({video:myfile,cool:'uploading'},()=>{
            const uploadVideo = async (base64enco) => {
                try {

                    const apiss = Axios.create({
                        baseURL: 'http://localhost:3005/upload',
                    })

                    console.log(this.state.video,this.state.cool)
                    let formData = new FormData()
                    formData.append("file", myfile)
                    console.log("uploading",formData,apiss)
                    const headers={
                        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                    }
                    apiss.post(`/video`, formData,{
                        headers:headers,
                        onUploadProgress: data => {
                            console.log(Math.round((100 * data.loaded) / data.total))
                          },
                    }).then(vid=>{
                        console.log(vid,"myvidss",vid.data.msg)
                        this.setState({videourl:vid.data.msg,cool:"uploaded"})
                    })
                    .catch(err=>{
                        console.log("err",err)
                    })

                    console.log('Video uploaded successfully');
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    console.log('Something went wrong!');
                }
        

            };

            uploadVideo(myfile);

        
        })
      
    };
    
    handleSubmitFile = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { names, imageurl, videourl }=this.state;
        const payload={names,imageurl,videourl}

        await api.insertVideo(payload).then((res) => {
            window.alert(`Movie inserted successfully`);
            console.log(this.state.cool)
            this.setState({
                names: "",
                rating: "",
                time: "",
            });
        });

    
}



    render(){
        console.log(this.state.cool)
        return(
            <div >
                <label>Name</label><br/>
                <input type="textbox" onChange={this.handleChangeInputName} value={this.state.names}/><br/>
                <label>Upload Image</label><br/>
                <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFileInputChange}/>
                <span style={{color:'blue'}}>{this.state.cools}</span><br/>
                <label>Upload Video</label><br/>
                <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFileVideoChange}/>
                <span style={{color:'blue'}}>{this.state.cool}</span><br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmitFile}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default VideosInsert;
```

I can upload videos and images using base64encoding to cloudinary but base64 encoding makes the video very large so I want to send only actual video data so I choose FormData() which I saw in many videos. But they used req.file.path which is not supported in today browsers. I get error stating path attribute is wriiten for undefined. How to send data from reactjs frontend to mongodb backend using FormData(). If not what is the best other alternative?

Comment: What is populating req.file.path? In my experience, it's usually set by a middleware like 'multer' - are you using that? If so, can you share the configuration? If not, what is making the file contents available to your Node code?

Comment: I updated the question @Igy .I am not using mutler. How to get the contents of files to server using formData and send it to cloudinary?

Comment: It looks like you're mixing implementation methods - you're calling `uploader.upload_large(req.body,` but the first parameter to `upload_large` should be a filename or a remote URL to fetch. In your server side code you likely need to use something like multer to take the POST request from your frontend and give you access to the file details, which can then be passed to Cloudinary's SDK